# How to get the corresponding value

Tags: java, algorithm

In a method `public V get(K key)`, if `key` exists, the method needs to return its corresponding `value`.
Let's say:

```
map.put("J",71);
map.put("O",29);
map.put("X",14);
map.put("I",11);
map.put("U",32);
map.put("B",19);
```

Im having trouble that if `key` exists, then how can I return its corresponding `value`? If, for example, the key is `"U"`, how should I return its value which is `32` with the method `get(K key)`? 
**ONLY ARRAYLISTS ARE ALLOWED**.

```
public abstract class AbstractListMM<K,V> implements IMiniMap<K,V>{

    private List <K> keys; 
    private List <V> values;

// Initialize the lists of keys and values with a concrete instance
public AbstractListMM(List <K> keys, List <V> values)
{
    this.keys = keys;
    this.values = values;
}

// Return the number of bindings based on the size of the key list
public int size()
{
    return keys.size();
}

// Based on the lists size
public boolean isEmpty()
{
     return (keys.isEmpty() && values.isEmpty());
}

// Make a (shallow) copy of the keys list and return it
public List<K> keys()
{
     List<K> newKeys = this.keys;
     return newKeys;
} 

// Make a (shallow) copy of the vals list and return it
public List<V> values()
{
    List<V> values = this.values;
    return values;
}

// Use this.indexOf() to locate the given key as quickly as possible
public boolean contains(K key)
{
    if(this.indexOf(key) < 0)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}

// Use this.indexOf() to determine if a given key is present and
// return its associated value; return null if the key is not
// present
//
// TARGET COMPLEXITY: Same speed as indexOf()
public V get(K key)
{
    if(this.indexOf(key) < 0)
        return null;
    else 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.values.size(); i++)
        {

        }
    }
}

// Use this.indexOf() to determine the location of the given
// key/value and remove it from the corresponding lists
//
// TARGET COMPLEXITY: O(N) due to list elements shifting
public V remove(K key);

// Find the numeric index of the key as quickly as possible based on
// the type of ListMM being implemented. Return a negative number if
// the given key is not present.
public abstract int indexOf(K key);

// Associate the given key with the given value in the
// lists. Creates an ordering of keys that is compatible with how
// indexOf() works to locate keys.
public abstract V put(K key, V value);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to store keys and values in *parallel lists*, meaning that when a key `k` is stored at index `i` of the `keys` list, then its corresponding value `v` is stored at index `i` of the `values` list. Therefore you can use the result of calling `indexOf` on `keys` to index into `values` when the index returned is non-negative:

```
public V get(K key) {
    int pos = keys.indexOf(key);
    if(pos < 0)
        return null;
    return values.get(pos);
}
```